# How to find a Control without knowing the parent control, narrowed by instance (.Net 1.1)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-1.1

I'm tasked with making a change to an old .Net 1.1 app that cannot be upgraded at this time.  The app is horribly designed, with calls all over the place, repeated functions, unused code that isn't even commented out, and multiple iterations of the same usercontrol without notation as to which one is actually being used.  The usercontrols which are used are mixed with controls that aren't user controls at all, but just as complex, when implemented in a central `Form`.

The central `Form` called `MainForm` has a `TabControl` which itself holds a `WorkForm`in each page.  These are generated dynamically from user input.  The `WorkForm` is a user control and contains the hodgepodge of user controls and contained/uncontained controls, panels, etc. mentioned before.   Parentage can be dynamic between a form and a control based entirely on data being loaded, which adds to the complexity of the problem.

An instance of a user control which is a part of the `WorkForm` user control on its 4th tab has a datagrid, and what I need to do is modify the code that adds a new row in that datagrid to check a control outside of the user control, but in the same `WorkForm`, and get its `SelectedValue`.   I essentially need to "Where's Waldo" the control I need, but with enough "Carmen Sandiego" to adapt to the fact that the control hierarchy is not guaranteed.  Also, the law of Demeter on this one is more like "Law of Demeter?  I don't even know her Dename!" so really kludgy calls to static variables that shouldn't be is pretty much how the app runs.

Something like:

```
Dim row as DataRow = aDataTable.NewRow()
    row[12] = Me.Parent.Cousin.TwiceRemoved.OnFathersSide.NotThatOne _
              .TheOtherOne.SelectedValue
```

What would be the best way to go about hunting down this control, since the relation isn't guaranteed?  P.S. I didn't write the app.  I'm just stuck with instructions to add a change to this nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on what you know about the control.

If it has a name (or and other kind of unique criteria) you could do a recursive search over all containers like this:

```
public static Control WhereInTheFormIsWaldoSandiego(Container c, String name)
{
  foreach (Control ctrl in c.Controls)
  {
    if (ctrl.Name.Equals(name)) return ctrl;
    if (ctrl is Container)
    {
      Control inner = WhereInTheFormIsWaldoSandiego(ctrl as Container, name);
      if (inner != null) return ctrl;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Otherwise your best bet would probably to find the logic that places the control and modify it to store a reference to it somewhere.

The later is probably preferable since it gives you better knowledge about the application but might also take much longer.

Comment: This is the best way to go about it in such a harried situation, though I was finally able to convince those further up the ladder to take a different approach.